# regex for ${(stringToMatch)}

Tags: java, regex, escaping, special-characters

I am using java Pattern Matcher api to search and replace tokens in a string. My string looks like below

```
Org Name: ${org_name}, Agent(s): ${agents}, OrgID: ${org_id}, ...
```

Here ${string} is the pattern I need to replace. I using regex like below

```
${(org_name|agents|org_id)}
```

But Pattern.compile is throwing exception. How to escape especial characters in this regex? or is there a better way of writing regex for this case?

Comment: Escape special regex metacharacters that you need to match *literally* and it will work.

Comment: So use `\\$\\{(org_name|agents|org_id)\\}` ... obey the @Wiktor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the curly brackets (`{` and `}`), which, in a regex pattern, imply quantifier; as well as the `$` sign, which implies the end of line. Simply use backslashes: `\`:

```
\$\{(org_name|agents|org_id)\}
```

If it is not parsed as literal pattern, and rather as a string, you'll need to use `\\`:

```
\\$\\{(org_name|agents|org_id)\\}
```

Try:

```
\\$\\{(org_(id|name)|agents)\\}
```

Comment: Thanks your answer worked. But I am using groovy language, so I had to add an extra \ to $ like this
`\\\$\\{(org_name|agents|org_id)\\}`